# Is there a way to fill parent minus a fixed number in Android RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-imagebutton, fill-parent

I have an `ImageButton` that I want to fill its parent `RelativeLayout` container for its width but minus a few `dp` so it has some left and right padding. I tried `fill_parent-10dp` but that causes an error and doesn't render.

Comment: what about _padding_ and _margin_?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Put a `android:layout_margin="10dp"` on the ImageButton, along with the

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Comment: fill_parent is now deprecated.

Answer (score 10):

1. Use the xml attribute `android:layout_marginLeft` to specifies extra
   space on the left side of your view.
2. Use the xml attribute `android:layout_marginRight` to specifies
   extra space on the right side of your view.
3. Use the xml attribute `android:layout_marginTop`to specifies extra
   space on the top side of your view.
4. Use the xml attribute `android:layout_marginBottom` to specifies
   extra space on the bottom side of your view.
5. Use the xml attribute `android:layout_margin` to specifies extra
   space on the left, top, right and bottom sides of your view.

In your case your ImageButton declaration look like this

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/a"
```